# submit form after user logs in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

The work flow I design for voting a poll is like:
The user can vote no matter if he logged in or not . If the user logged in, simply the form is submitted. If the user didn't log in, a modal showing up to ask user to log in with facebook to finish the vote. After he logged in, the form with the choice he voted before would be submit.

I am implementing with rails and seems after creating a session, the page is redirected. Even if back to the same page, How can I submit the form with the choice he chose? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onemethod would be remmber what the person chose by,

1) sending the values as GET parameter while logging with facebook

2) other would be to store in a cookie and retrieve it back while posting

Answer (score 0):

Save the vote in a session variable. After user logs in put in a hidden variable.Then simply submit the form using a function. You can add the function on body tag like

```
<body onload="fnc()">
<script type="text/javascript">
fnc()
{
document.getElementById("yourformId").submit();
}
</script>
```

There might be other way. But this hid me on the first place